# Which verse of taittiriya brAhmana talks of extinguishing agnihotra fire as sinful?

Tags: vedas, sin, vedic-rituals, agni

The book Hindu Dharma (comprised of speeches given by [Chandrashekarendra Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati)) states [in this chapter](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part12/chap9.htm) that:

> The Taittiriya Brahmana has it that to extinguish the agnihotra fire
>   is to earn the demerit of killing a hero.

I want to know which verse speaks of the above mentioned statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's Taittirīya Saṃhitā (TS 1.5.2.1) not the Brāhmaṇa you are referring to.

Translation of the verse from [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv01.htm):

> i. 5. 2. 
>   He who removes the fire casts away the sacrifice and cattle. The sacrificial cake is offered on five potsherds; the sacrifice is fivefold, cattle are fivefold; verily he wins the sacrifice and cattle. **Now he who removes the fire is the slayer of the hero among the gods**; Brahmans desirous of holiness did not aforetime eat his food; the Yajyas and Anuvakyas are in the Pankti metre; the sacrifice is fivefold, man is fivefold; verily making recompense to the gods for the hero he re-establishes the fire [1].

Sanskrit (IAST) verse from [here](http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/yvs/ts/ts.htm?ts005.htm):

> Paragraph: 2  
>   Verse: 1  
>   Sentence: 1    párā vā́ eṣá yajñám paśū́n vapati yò 'gním udvāsáyate / 
>   Sentence: 2    páñcakapālaḥ puroḍāśo bʰavati 
>   Sentence: 3    pā́ṅkto yajñáḥ pā́ṅktāḥ paśávo yajñám evá paśū́n ávarunddʰe / 
>   Sentence: 4    **vīrahā́ vā́ eṣá devā́nāṃ yò 'gním udvāsáyate** 
>   Sentence: 5    ná vā́ etásya brāhmaṇā́ r̥tāyávaḥ purā́nnam akṣan / 
>   Sentence: 6    paṅktyò yājyānuvākyā̀ bʰavanti 
>   Sentence: 7    pā́ṅkto yajñáḥ pā́ṅktaḥ púruṣo devā́n evá vīráṃ niravadā́yāgním púnar ā //

Also see: [What is Virahatya (Killing of a hero)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30283)