# What is Virahatya (Killing of a hero)?

Tags: dharma, sin, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, prayaschitta

Here is what the **Manusmriti 11.41** says:

> If a Brāhmaṇa who has set up the fires neglects them wilfully, he
>   shall perform the ‘Cāndrāyaṇa’ penance for a month; as his offence is
>   equal to the **offence of killing a hero**.—(41)

Here is the verse in Sanskrit:

> agnihotryapavidhyāgnīn brāhmaṇaḥ kāmakārataḥ |  cāndrāyaṇaṃ caren
>   māsaṃ **vīrahatyā**samaṃ hi tat

Now, *vira* means 'hero', and *hatya* means 'killing', so *virahatya* means 'killing of a hero'.

But my question is, what does 'hero' mean in the context of this sin?

Comment: hero = fire according to Patrick Olivelle's [notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rPKw.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the [meanings](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=vIra&direct=se) of **vīra** is **son**. It also mean **warrior** or **Kshatriya**.

And, one of the [meanings](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=vIrahatyA&script=hk&direct=se&link=didse&mode=3) of vīrahatyā is **murder of son**.

---

Also, [other translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu11.htm) of **Manu Smriti 11.41** verse is as below

> 41. A Brahmana who, being an Agnihotrin, voluntarily neglects the sacred fires, shall perform a lunar penance during one month; for that (offence) is equal to the **slaughter of a son**.

---

[Explanatory notes by Ganganath Jha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201917.html) on the verse have the following:

> ‘Vīra’—‘**Son**’ (Govindarāja, Kullūka, Nārāyaṇa and Rāghavānanda);—‘a Kṣatriya’ (Nandana);—‘a deity’ (suggested by Rāghavānanda).

Comment: 'slaughter of a son' doesn't make sense. Every man is somebody else's son. Slaughter of a young person/boy or Kṣatriya makes more sense. Medhātithi’s commentary - "he who allows the fires to become extinguished is regarded by the gods as the slayer of a hero." - is totally different; maybe this is what it really means.

Comment: @sv. It might be talking about your own son.