# What is the Vedic definition of Sannyasa?

Tags: vedas, moksha, meditation, vivekananda, sannyasa

As I've heard,according to the Vedas, ***sannysa***, the fourth Vedic ashrama, is to follow ***vanaprastha***, the 3rd Vedic ashrama, and meant to attain ***moksha***. Thus, the right definition of ***snnyasa*** seems to be the renunciation of the world, and so a true sannyasin is expected to be lost in deep meditation in a solitary mountain cave or a dense-forest retreat till ***death***. Nevertheless, **Adi Shankara**, ***Vivekananda***, etc. Great sannyasins are known **Not** to have renounced the worldly life. Vivekananda also defined sannyasa as ' the **love** of life ' and thus justified a sannyasin's stay among worldly people, leading a worldly life and enjoyment of almost all ***pleasures*** of life. Thus, I feel most confused. I'm curious to know the Right Vedic definition of ***sannyasa***.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32052/647

Comment: Your 'question' is filled with your own opinion and is more aimed at asking 'am I right'? Not aware of Vivekananda ever defining sannays as you say, nor am I aware that 'great sannyains are known NOT to have renounced the world'. Please edit your question and not your opinions. References to sannyas can be found in Brahma Sutras 3.4.17-20; Mahanarayana Upanishad 78.12; Chandogya Upanishad 2.23.1-2 and 5.10.1; Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 4.4.22; Mundaka Upanishad 1.2.11; Jabala Upanishad 4;  Also see the Gita.

Comment: Adi Shankara, Vivekananda, etc. Great sannyasins are known Not to have renounced the worldly life. Thanks for the links. Nevertheless, by the Vedic definition of sannyasa, I meant a statement that's in harmony with the Vedic ' References to sannyas '.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is defined in the **Sannyasa Upanishad**:

**Verse**

> अथातः **संन्यासोपनिषदं व्याख्यास्यामो** योऽनुक्रमेण **संन्यस्यति स संन्यस्तो
> भवति। कोऽयं संन्यास उच्यते । कथं संन्यस्तो भवति** । य आत्मानं
> क्रियाभिर्गुप्तं करोति मातरं पितरं भार्यां पुत्रान्बन्धूननुमोदयित्वा
> ये चास्यर्त्विजस्तान्सर्वांश्च पूर्ववद्वृणीत्वा वैश्वानरेटिं
> निर्वपेत्स-र्वस्वं दद्याद्यजमानस्य गा ऋत्विजः सर्वैः पात्रैः समारोप्य
> यदाहवनीये गार्हपत्ये वान्वाहार्यपचने सभ्यावसथ्ययोश्च
> प्राणापानव्यानोदानसमानान्सर्वान्सर्वेषु
> समारोपयेत्।सशिखान्केशान्विसृज्य यज्ञोपवीतं छित्त्वा पुत्रं दृष्ट्वा
> त्वं यज्ञस्त्वं सर्वमित्यनुमन्त्रयेत्। यद्यपुत्रो भवत्यात्मानमेवेमं
> ध्यात्वा- ऽनवेक्षमाणः प्राचीमुदीचीं वा दिशं प्रव्रजेच्च।चतुर्षु
> वर्णेषु भिक्षाचर्यं चरेत्।पाणिपात्रेणाशनं कुर्यात् औषधवदशनमाचरेत्।
> औषधवदशनं प्राश्नीयात् । यथालाभमश्नीयात्प्राणसंधारणार्थं यथा
> मेदोवृद्धिर्न जायते । कृशो भूत्वा ग्राम एकरात्रं नगरे पञ्चरात्रं चतुरो
> मासान्वार्षिकान्ग्रामे वा नगरे वापि वसेत् । पक्षा वै मासो इति द्वौ
> मासौ वा वसेत् । विशीर्णवस्त्रं वल्कलं वा
> प्रतिगृह्णीयान्नान्यत्प्रतिगृह्णीयाद्यद्यशक्तो भवति क्लेशतस्तप्यते तप
> इति । यो वा एवं क्रमेण संन्यस्यति यो वा एवं पश्यति किमस्य यज्ञोपवीतं
> कास्य शिखा कथं वास्योपस्पर्शनमिति । तं होवाचेदमेवास्य तद्यज्ञोपवीतं
> यदात्मध्यानं विद्या शिखा नीरैः सर्वत्रावस्थितैः कार्यं
> निर्वर्तयन्नुदरपात्रेण जलतीरे निकेतनम्। ब्रह्मवादिनो वदन्त्यस्तमित
> आदित्ये कथं वास्योपस्पर्शनमिति । तान्होवाच यथाहनि तथा रात्रौ नास्य
> नक्तं न दिवा तदप्येतदृषिणोक्तम्। सकृद्दिवा हैवास्मै भवति य एवं
> विद्वानेतेनात्मानं संधत्ते ॥

**Meaning in English**

> Now we shall expound the Upanishad on **renunciation**. He who in due
> order (of the stages of life) gives up (the primary inclinations such
> as the desire for wealth, etc.,) becomes one who has renounced
> (worldly life). **What is this called renunciation ? How does one
> renounce** ? One who guards himself by the (following) activities, who
> has (for his renunciation) the approval of mother, father, wife, sons
> and kinsmen should assemble all the officiating priests known to him
> and as before (with their approval) perform the Vaishvanara sacrifice
> (for the welfare of all people). He shall (after partition) give away
> all his wealth to the officiating priests. For the priests are the
> singers (of the Vedic hymns, deserving the gift). The (five) vital
> airs, Prana, Apana, Vyana, Udana and Samana, shall be (symbolically)
> placed in all the sacrificial vessels over the (five) sacred fires,
> the ahavaniya, garhapatya, anvaharyapachana, sabhya and avasathya.
> Shaving off his hair along with the tuft, snapping the sacred thread
> and seeing his son, he shall consecrate (himself) with the mantras
> ‘You are the god Brahma, you are the sacrifice, you are everything’.
> If he has no son he should consecrate himself thus and not minding
> (anything) proceed as a mendicant monk eastward or northward.
>
> He may receive alms from (people of the) four castes. He should eat
> from the vessel of his hands. He shall consider food as medicine. He
> should take food as medicine (i.e. in great moderation). He should eat
> as and when he gets (food, without discontent and not asking for more,
> like Oliver Twist) for bare sustenance and in such a way that there is
> no increase of fat. Having grown lean he may shelter one night in a
> village, five nights in a town; he may reside during the four rainy
> months in a village or town. (Interpreting) fortnights as months, he
> may reside (in a fixed abode) for two months. If he is unable to
> endure (heat or cold) he may accept as gift a tattered garment or bark
> dress. He shall not accept any other. For penance is to suffer pain
> (with equanimity). What then is the sacred thread, the tuft and the
> ceremonial sipping of water to one who thus renounces in the
> prescribed manner and who thus views it (in the correct perspective) ?
> To him (the questioner) is this reply.  This is his sacred thread
> (namely) that he meditates on the Atman; the (practice of)
> Brahma-vidya is the tuft; that he quenches his thirst with the vessel
> of his belly accomplishes (the ceremonial) duty with water that is
> present everywhere. His residence is at the bank of (a reservoir of)
> water. When the sun has set, how can he (ceremoniously) sip water ? As
> (he touches water) during day, so at night; (for) he has neither night
> nor day. (The enlightened ascetic is above the restrictions of time).
> This has been said by the Vedic sage (in a mantra): ‘To him there is
> (only) one (time), the day.’ He who knows thus realizes the Atman
> through this (renunciation).

**Hindi Meaning**

> अब **संन्यास उपनिषद्** का वर्णन करते हैं। **क्रमानुसार नश्वर जगत् का
> परित्याग कर देने वाला विरक्त ही संन्यासी होता है**। (प्रश्न) संन्यास
> किसे कहते हैं? संन्यासी किस तरह का होता है ? (उत्तर) संन्यासी वह है,जो
> आत्मा के उत्थान हेतु माता-पिता, स्त्री-पुत्र, बान्धव आदि के द्वारा
> अनुमोदित पूर्व में कही क्रियाओं का परित्याग कर देता है; जो हमेशा की
> तरह ऋत्विजों को नमन-वंदन करने के पश्चात् वैश्वानर यज्ञ सम्पन्न करता
> है। इस पुनीत अवसर पर यजमान अपना सभी कुछ दान कर दे तथा ऋत्विज् सम्पूर्ण
> सामग्री को पात्रों समेत हवन कर दे। संन्यासी द्वारा आहवनीय, गार्हपत्य,
> दक्षिणाग्नि इन तीनों अग्नियों तथा सभ्य (वैदिक कालीन अग्नि) एवं आवसथ्य
> (स्मृतिकालीन अग्नि) को प्राण, अपान, व्यान, उदान एवं समान पाँचों वायुओं
> में आरोपित करना चाहिए। शिखा (चोटी) सहित सभी केशों का मुण्डन करा देना
> चाहिए। यज्ञोपवीत को त्याग दे एवं पुत्र को देखकर इस तरह कहे कि तुम यज्ञ
> रूप हो, सर्वस्वरूप हो। यदि पुत्र न हो, तो वह अपनी आत्मा को ही लक्ष्य
> करके उपदेश देकर पूर्व अथवा उत्तर दिशा की ओर गमन कर जाए। चारों वर्णों
> (ब्राह्मण, क्षत्रिय, वैश्य एवं शुद्र) से भिक्षा स्वीकार करनी चाहिए।
> हाथ रूपी पात्र में भिक्षा ग्रहण कर भोजन करना चाहिए। भोजन को औषधि के
> समान ग्रहण करना चाहिए अर्थात् मात्र प्राण रक्षा की दृष्टि से आहार लेना
> चाहिए और जो कुछ प्राप्त हो जाए, वही ग्रहण करना चाहिए, जिससे चर्बी की
> वृद्धि न हो। इस प्रकार क्षीणकाय होकर गाँव में एक रात्रि एवं नगर में
> पाँच रात्रि तक निवास करना चाहिए। चातुर्मास (वर्षा के मास) में एक ही
> गाँव अथवा नगर में रुक जाना चाहिए या फिर पक्ष (पखवारा) को ही मास समझकर
> दो महीने तक निवास करना चाहिए। फटे वस्त्र अथवा वल्कल वस्त्र ही धारण
> करना चाहिए, अन्य वस्त्रों को ग्रहण न करे। इस तरह क्लेश सहना ही
> तप-तितिक्षा है। जो इस क्रम से संन्यास धारण करता है, उसके लिए यज्ञोपवीत
> क्या है? शिखा क्या है? आचमन किस तरह का है? इन सभी का उत्तर इस प्रकार
> है- आत्मा का ध्यान ही संन्यासी का यज्ञोपवीत है। विद्या ही उसकी शिखा
> (चोटी) है। सर्वत्र स्थित जल के लिए उदर (पेट) ही संन्यासी का पात्र है
> तथा जलाशय का तट ही उसका आश्रय-स्थल है। इसी प्रकार का ब्रह्मवादी भी
> होता है। उसके लिए सूर्य के अस्ताचल की ओर गमन करने पर आचमन किस तरह का
> है? इस प्रश्न का उत्तर इस प्रकार है-उस (संन्यासी) के लिए रात्रि एवं
> दिन दोनों ही एक जैसे हैं। उसके लिए न रात्रि होती है, न दिन होता है। जो
> (संन्यासी अथवा साधक) अपनी आत्मा के अनुसंधान में सतत लगा रहता है,
> विद्वज्जनों के अनुसार उसके लिए सदैव दिन ही है ॥