# Is there any scriptural injuctions that says leaving 'Agni-seva' is a sin in kaliyuga?

Tags: sin, kali-yuga, vedic-rituals, agni

Agni-seva was treated as a noble virtue in the Vedic ages.

Is there any scriptural injuctions that says leaving 'Agni-seva' is a sin in kaliyuga?

Comment: You can see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32053/4732

Comment: @Rickross Thanks, but Manu-smriti says : 'Daanam ekam kalau yuge' while Taittiriya Samhita does not say anything about yuga, The Kali-santarana-Upanishad says Hari Naama is the way and the Tantra says that in the kali-yuga, the rituals of the Vedas are fruitless.

Comment: I think that Vedic injunction can taken to be applicable in every yuga

Comment: @Rickross on what basis ?

Comment: Not sure but people say Vedas are eternal so what they say must be eternally true ..

Comment: @Rickross Why Manu-Smriti does says something different?

Comment: @Rickross that eternal is the 'knowledge'.But different yajnas and offerings have been stopped by other scriptures

Comment: What does manu smriti say in this regard? I think it says even in the forests the ascetics must continue to do fire worship

Comment: @Rickross Why it says DANAMEKAM KALAU YUGE?

Comment: @Rickross ascetics are not common men.

Comment: I think that means Charity works the best in Kali but that does not mean one can extinguish the sacred fire .. Parashara Smriti also says the same but it also includes daily Agnihotra as one of the 6 duties of a Brahmin

Comment: I am talking about the last Asrama people .. Sannyas is also an Asrama ..